# Using Google Drive for backups; don't want to back up .class and other non-source files

Tags: android, netbeans

I use Netbeans 8.0.2 and Android Studio 1.2.2 (AS) and they produce a LOT of files during compilation (over 100 for Netbeans, often well over 1000 for AS).

When I let Google Drive back up my stuff (or my own program to back up changed files to external hard drive), I'd rather it only be the source files (.java, .src, .xml, .build, etc.), but, as I have it currently set up, EVERYTHING is in Google Drive folder. It takes far too long, but I'm prepared to continue living with that, since this is maybe as it must and should be.

But I'll ask what may be a dumb question:

Can I have generated files and source files saved in different parts of my directory structure (the former outside, the latter inside Google Drive folder)? This is especially important in AS.

Let me say that I will be shocked if there is a way to do this, so please accept that statement as a pre-emptive strike against comments of the form/intent of `"Are you {insane | stupid | kidding | ... }?"`!

Answer (score 1):

There is a option on the File menu for Export Project -> to Zip that works pretty well. It will create a zip file that has only the source and project files but not .class, .jar files that were built. This should be small enough for you to upload/download unless you have a ton of source. You can also import a project directly from the zip without having to extract the files first.

If you don't need to keep the files private, GitHub is actually a much better option. You can have lots and lots of versions and only the differences between files need to be uploaded/downloaded. Add a comment if you need more detail.